# Parse TSV(text) files and get values from a column

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have a bunch of TSV files in a folder that I'm trying to parse and get some information. Each file has different columns (with different headers), but one of the columns is definitely common across all the files. I have a list of headers that I'm interested in, in a text file. I'm parsing that file and tried using uniVocity parsing tool to get the information of those particular columns. It worked when I tried with one or two headers, but is returning nothing when all the headers in the file are passed.

Here's my code:

```
import com.univocity.parsers.tsv.TsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.tsv.TsvParserSettings;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import static com.univocity.parsers.conversions.Conversions.toLowerCase;


public class getdata {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {

        String filename = "tmp_collist.txt";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>(10000);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        String str = lines.toString().replaceFirst("\\[", "");
        StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        //str = '"' + _sb;
        str = _sb.insert(0, '"').toString();
        if (str != null && str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == ']') {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        }
        str += '"';
        str = str.replace(", ", "\",\"");
        //System.out.print(str);
        //reader.close();
        File folder = new File("folder_location");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            File file1 = listOfFiles[i];
            if (file1.isFile() && file1.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings();
                settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
                settings.selectFields(str);
                TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);
                List<String[]> resolvedData = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(file1));
                for (String[] row : resolvedData) {
                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String col : row) {
                        strBuilder.append(col).append("\t");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the TSV files are like:

sample_file1.txt

```
header1 header2 header3
val11   val21   val31
val12   val22   val32
```

sample_file2.txt

```
header1 header5 header3
val11   val51   val35
val14   val54   val38
```

tmp_collist.txt has headers list that I need. It is a file with one column:

```
header2
header3
header9
header8
```

I'd like to get a list (if possible, unique) of all the header1 values, for each of the value in the headers provided (it can be in a file or anything).

Comment: So it sounds like a join between tables (files) based on a common column (`header1`). Does that about summarize what you need?

Comment: @YoYo Yes. That's what I need.

Comment: It seems to me more convenient to load the data in database, and use SQL to accomplish this, or use api's that offer SQL like operations on arbitrary datasets. Is that even an option?

Comment: @YoYo SQL like operations sound like a good idea. I'd really appreciate if you could guide me through it. I'm very very new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the library and just found an issue with the field selection when there are mismatching header names (see [here](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/86)).

Try getting the latest version (2.1.1-SNAPSHOT) and when you select headers that are not present in the input file, you will get the expected result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't see 2.1.1 listed in here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/

Comment: its a snapshot build currently: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/